# Could md5 algrithom generate the same string with the original string?

Tags: java, md5

I found [this](https://github.com/elliottkember/The-Kember-Identity) on github occasionally.

```
md5(text).equals(text)
```

Could this happen in common use?

Comment: Considering that's not how you compare Strings in java, it's unlikely to work, period. Aside from that, it's unclear what you're asking. The project you link to is about *trying to find* a string that MD5s to itself.

Comment: Why you not just following the "Kember Identity" which is also referenced on your linked github resource? http://elliottkember.com/kember_identity.html

Comment: @BrianRoach I have edited assuming that the op was not asking that.

Comment: @assylias I didn't find that question.Thanks for editing my question. :)

Comment: @Stefan I'll remeber it next time.thanks

Comment: @BrianRoach I thought there are alot of people don't know Java grammer.So I take a simple expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MD5 is hash algorithm, with collisions. That means that there can be two strings X and Y with same hash.

But this seems incorrect. I'm no expert in hashing, but my gut feeling is, this will be always false.

There is some more info in the linked blog post and corresponding comments - http://elliottkember.com/kember_identity.html

Comment: It depends on the underlying algorithm. They usually use simple operation (bitwise shifts, additions multiplications etc.) over fixed size chunks of the original data.